# Cannot Start Passenger 3.0.18 Using Mountain Lion (OS X Server) and RVM

Tags: apache2, osx-mountain-lion, passenger

I recently did a clean install of Mountain Lion on my Mac Mini Server.

I installed version 3.0.18 using a gem according to the directions on http://www.phusionpassenger.com with no errors that I could see.

```
rvmsudo gem install passenger-enterprise-server-3.0.18.gem
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Here are my entries in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf with my username masked:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-enterprise-server-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /Users/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ruby
```

I uncommented out the following statement:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Here is a sample virtual host entry.  I have three of them in the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  PassengerAppRoot /Users/username/Sites/myfolder/
  DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/myfolder/public
  <Directory /Users/username/Sites/myfolder/public>
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted Apache several times.  Here is information from my server:

```
[~]$ ps -ef | grep Passenger
  501 18804   303   0 12:39PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep Passenger
[~]$ rvmsudo passenger-status
Password:
**ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.**
[~]$ rvmsudo passenger-config --version  
3.0.18
```

I have tried doing online searches on this.  I was surprised that there was not all that much on this specific error even though from my understanding Passenger has been around for a few years.  I have posted this issue on the Phusion Passenger Google Groups but have not heard anything.

Any help would be appreciated, the sooner the better LOL.  Seriously I need to have one of my three websites up by tomorrow evening.  This is the only issue stopping that from happening.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I continued searching but still did not find anything on this error for people using Mountain Lion.  After several days of utter frustration I decided to contact Phusion since I had recently purchased one of the support packages.  The support I received was more than worth what I paid for it.  I had come to the conclusion that something must have changed somewhere between Lion and Mountain Lion but did not know where to look.

The setup I tried after upgrading to Mountain Lion (OS X Server) worked perfectly when I used Passenger with Lion Server.  After a lot of extensive checking the support person decided to try making the changes I made in **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** in the config file for the Web Service located in **/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf**.  All my Rails applications loaded perfectly.  Apparently the other config file is either ignored or something.  When the support person led me in trying things in **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** and checking logs nothing appeared in them.  This is when he decided to try updating the Web Service config file.

Note: I have to give a shout out to the support team at Phusion.  When I tell you that they searched for a needle in a haystack I am not exaggerating.  I created several files with notes from their support that I hope to never have to use again.  They were excellent and very easy to work with.